# Case sensitive cmd autocompletion

Tags: vim

How do I disable case insensitive cmd autocompletion, but keep search case insensitive (`ignorecase` and `smartcase`)?

For example, if I enter `:e li` in a directory with two candidates - LICENSE and lib/ and hit tab, I'll get `:e LICENSE` instead of `:e lib/` I would like to get...

EDIT: I'm using vim under cygwin.

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you are describing. When I hit tab on `:e l` I get `:e lib/`. When I hit tab on `:e L` I get `:e LICENCE`. You wouldn't happen to be on a case insensitive file system would you (such as osx)

Comment: @FDinoff it's Cygwin, should've specified that.

Comment: Cygwin is also case insensitive. I don't think you are going to be able to work around it. (I do not recommend making cygwin case sensitive)

Comment: I think that the only solution is to fix Vim source code.

Comment: @FDinoff: The Cygwin shell completes sensitively exactly as OP wants. You fan type `cd LIB` and it will change to `lib` if that's what's there, but if you type `cd L<tab>` it will not match `lib`. Vim will and for people used to typing correct case it's pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options `wildignorecase` and `fileignorecase` control what you want (added in 7.3.872, upgrade ViM if you have older).

This should do the trick for you:

```
:set nofileignorecase
:set nowildignorecase
```

Not sure about Cygwin, but that definitely works on OSX.

Comment: I have vim 7.3, `nowildignorecase` didn't change anything; my vim doens't seem to have `nofileignorecase`. What ver do I need for that? Can't find anything online.

Comment: I'm using 7.4 (MacVim 70) on OSX. `wildignorecase` only takes effect if `fileignorecase` is not set. I'm now trying to investigate why you don't have `fileignorecase`. Are you sure about that?

Comment: I get error while trying to set it: `E518: Unknown option: fileignorecase`

Comment: It seems option `fileignorecase` was added in 7.3.872. I'd recommend you to update to 7.4 and try again.

Comment: I think nofileignorecase is the only one you need

Comment: Upgraded to Vim 7.4 to try it out, but it does not seem to work on Windows. The options don't seem to have any effect.